# ServiceStackHost.Instance has already been set

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, servicestack, nuget

I have a bizarre problem.

I have implemented a standard Service Stack API.

It has been working perfect for the last year now.

Last week I saw some major changes to Xamarin Studio so decided to update my IDE.

With that update NuGet comes standard, so I decided to convert my Service Stack Reference Files to use NuGet. Quite nice, now I can update the DLL's etc with 1 click.

So the API works fine on my Windows Machine now, no issues.

Problem: Our servers run Ubuntu with Mono installed. And it does not want to budge.

I Initially get this Error:

```
System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.FileSystemVirtualPathProvider..ctor (IAppHost appHost, System.IO.DirectoryInfo rootDirInfo) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.FileSystemVirtualPathProvider..ctor (IAppHost appHost, System.String rootDirectoryPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at API_NOTIFICATION.Global.Application_Start (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Then I refresh the page and I keep getting this  error:

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: ServiceStackHost.Instance has already been set
  at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at API_NOTIFICATION.Global.Application_Start (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Anyone Experienced this before? Anyone know how to fix this?

I did look at other posts similar to this one.

No idea where to find:

```
App_Start/ServiceStackFramework.cs
```

And no idea how to remove as again I cant find that anywhere. But who knows, it might not even be the same problem at all.

I have used the standard Tutorial to set up the API which is posted on the ServiceStack Website.

Any help will be much appreciated. And like I said, the only think that really changed is the IDE and updating those ServiceStack references via NuGet.

AppHost:

```
public class ResponseNotificationServiceAppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public ResponseNotificationServiceAppHost() : base("Response Notification Services", typeof(NotificationServices).Assembly)
    {
    }

    #region implemented abstract members of AppHostBase

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Global:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{       
    protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new ResponseNotificationServiceAppHost().Init();
    }
}
```

API Service Class:

```
public class NotificationServices : Service
{
     public PersonNotificationResponse Any(PersonNotification request) 
     {
          // Implementation Code here
     }
}
```

Update:

When trying to remove the AppHost, the API would not load. I get the following error on the Ubuntu Server:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: This is due to the AppHost being initialized twice. Are you using WebActivator or have any other AppHost in your project? Also what NuGet package are you using?

Comment: Not using Web Activator as far as i Know. I tried finding where it is initializing it twice and cant find it anywhere. The only AppHost I'm using it the one that I created in the Global.asax.cs file. There are no other ones in the project. I'm using "ServiceStack webservice framework: Faster,Cleaner ....." https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack. Strange thing is, that   it works fine on windows, just not when I push the DDL's up to the Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Oh, Also tried removing that AppHost from my Global.asax.cs, but it would not load the API on my development machine.

Comment: This is the error I get on Ubuntu Server if I remove that AppHost: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Comment: Ok it must be related to the initial exception you're getting, do you have this code in a GitHub repo somewhere?

Comment: This is for a project at my job. Going to be tricky to release the source. Lots of IP involved. And I think you are right, it must be related to the first internal exception message that gets thrown.

Comment: Looks like it might be Ubuntu 12.04. The solution works on Ubuntu 14.04 with the latest Mono Build.

Comment: Thank you @mythz for always responding to my Service Stack related question so fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a problem with the mono framework.

The server was running on 2.10.5 Mono on a 12.04 LTS server.

I hosted the API on a new 14.04 LST server with Mono 3.2.6 installed.

Works fine now.

Maybe ServiceStack was updated which was not compatible with 2.10.5 anymore. Not sure, can only speculate.